# Why does the tool "readelf" outputs two ELF file section count numbers?

Tags: linux, elf, binutils

I am currently investigating an issue with our tool which reads and interprets ELF files, that has an problem reading a specific elf file.

The unix tool "readelf" with the option "-h" outputs 2 values for the parameter "Number of section headers". There is an additional one after the initial number.

Example for the file that works:

```
Number of section headers: 1234
```

Example for the file that does not work:

```
Number of section headers: 0 (4524)
```

What does the number in the brackets mean? I guess it could be the cause for my issue as our application thinks there are no sections in the problematic file.

[image: console screen]

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show the text itself.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the relevant code in the readelf source.](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/1bc5b62129b45aeb860af1002bfef199a1850755/binutils/readelf.c#L5207).  It looks like if `header->e_shnum` has the value `SHN_UNDEF` [(zero)](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/blob/3451a2d7a3501e9c3fc344cbc4950c495f30c16d/include/elf/internal.h#L51) then what's printed in parentheses is the value of `filedata->section_headers[0].sh_size`.

This corresponds to the following passage in the [`elf(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html):

> ```
>    e_shnum
>           This member holds the number of entries in the section
>           header table.  Thus the product of e_shentsize and e_shnum
>           gives the section header table's size in bytes.  If a file
>           has no section header table, e_shnum holds the value of
>           zero.
>
>           If the number of entries in the section header table is
>           larger than or equal to SHN_LORESERVE (0xff00), e_shnum
>           holds the value zero and the real number of entries in the
>           section header table is held in the sh_size member of the
>           initial entry in section header table.  Otherwise, the
>           sh_size member of the initial entry in the section header
>           table holds the value zero.
> ```

So this would be a valid way to specify that the section header table has 74496 entries (which indeed is larger than `0xff00`).  It seems you need to fix your tool to handle this case.